# Ember.js can't display own template

Tags: ember.js

I have just started to follow some tutorials and suddenly got a problem with displaying a template. 
I can't display any template other than the default one.

The following code is placed just after the default handlebar (which is doing well) in the index.html->body:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='myTemplateName'>
    <h2>Why can not I just be shown?</h2>
</script>
```

I had created a view file which is referenced in the index.html correctly:

```
MovieTracker.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'application'
});

MovieTracker.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'myTemplateName'
});
```

The problem is that I'm not getting any errors (checked with firebug console),
but the content of 'myTemplateName' isn't shown.

Why can't I add my own templates, while the default one works fine?

I'll appreciate a lot your help, It's very important to me,
and I searched all over the internet without finding anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has your application template got an {{outlet}} ? Where are you linking to your template?

```
{{#link-to 'myTemplateName'}}Your Template{{/link-to}}
```

Have you set up a route?

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("myTemplateName", { path: "/myTemplateName" });
});
```

Once the handlebars link to is clicked it should populate your {{outlet}} in your main template with the correct template.

Comment: Hi Dan, now I am  getting two errors: 1)Error: There is no route named myTemplateName.index 
2) The attempt to link-to route 'myTemplateName' failed (also tried 'myTemplateName.index'). The router did not find 'myTemplateName' in its possible routes: 'loading', 'error', 'index'. I did excactly what you said.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What have you named your app? If it is different than App replace the App.Router.map with [insert-your-app-name].Router.map and make sure whichever js file it is in being included.

Comment: OK Thank you very much! You helped me a lot, now I can continue!